# Blackberry Java String to date conversion

Tags: java, string, blackberry, java-me, datetime-format

I used following code to convert string to date but it is applying timezone of device while conversion.
I don't need this but I want same date/time from that string like

```
String = "2009-07-31 07:59:17.427"
Date = 2009-07-31 07:59:17.427

Date formatter = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse("2009-07-31 07:59:17.427"));
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String strCustomDateTime = dateFormat.format(formatter);
```

Answer (score 6):

You may take in account default timezone offset to date you get after parsing:

```
public static String StringToDate(String dateToParse) {

    Date formatter = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(dateToParse));
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
    formatter.setTime(formatter.getTime() + offset);
    String strCustomDateTime = dateFormat.format(formatter);
    return strCustomDateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem, exactly? You are trying to convert "2009-07-31 07:59:17.427" into a point in time, but, this does not specify a unique point in time -- without a timezone. So you do need a timezone, and the library is necessary picking one, the platform's current timezone.

If the problem is you wish to specify a different time zone, then call DateFormat.setTimeZone():

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("your time zone"));
```

Comment: I get an error for the setTimeZone method in Blackberry. I just want to get the Date representation which is string format to the date format as is.